# How to add limit ad load retries inside onAdFailedToLoad() in Admob Ads?

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

Within the guide on how to place Admob interstitial ads in the app, you have the following warning:

> Warning: Attempting to load a new ad from the `onAdFailedToLoad ()` method is strongly discouraged. If you must load an ad from `onAdFailedToLoad ()`, limit ad load retries to avoid continuously failed ad requests in situations such as limited network connectivity.

I was putting a

```
mInterstitialAd.loadAd (new AdRequest.Builder (). build ());
```

inside the `onAdFailedToLoad ()` and it seems that this is not the correct one.
What is the best practice for doing this type of limit within the `onAdFailedToLoad ()`?

Comment: you have to create a function where you call load ad again and put a counter in the function to count how many times you have loaded the ad. for example the value can be 3. after count == 3 return from function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe create the maximum number of new requests?

```
const val MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_AD_REQUEST = 5

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private var loadAdInterstitialRequests = 0
}
```

And then in `AdListener`:

```
override fun onAdFailedToLoad(p0: Int)
{
    super.onAdFailedToLoad(p0)
    if (loadAdInterstitialRequests++ < MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_AD_REQUEST)
    {
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
    }
}
```

This will limit sending new add requests to `MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_AD_REQUEST`.